# select the most nested element with same classes

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make some special menu but i have a problem with selecting the most nested element (div) . Menu will be dynamic so it can change how much divs will be nested in one div. (parents will be created with new childs) so i need to select the last one (the most nested) without using more classes od Ids. 
Here is a code i wrote until now:

```
<div id="strategy">
  <div class="selected">
  0
    <div class="selected">
    some text
      <div class="selected"> this is the last div, but it can be anytime     changed and more childs of this element can be created</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="selected">
1
</div>
<div>
2
</div>
</div>
```

and something of css i tried:

`div.selected:only-of-type {background: #F00;}`
also tried nth:last-child, only-child.. i  think everything but there must be some way how to do it.

Comment: Without knowing the depth of your deepest element, this isn't possible with CSS alone. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: In jQuery, the selector is `.selected:not(:has(.selected))`

Comment: If you are accepting jquery solutions please tag the question with it or mention that you are not accepting jquery soltions

Answer (score 0):

if you're open to jQuery...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $target = $('#strategy').children();

  while( $target.length ) {
    $target = $target.children();
  }

  var last = $target.end(); // You need .end() to get to the last matched set
  var lastHtml = last.html();
  $('body').append('<strong>deepest child is: ' + lastHtml + '</strong>');
  last.css('color', 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="strategy">
  <div class="selected">
    0
    <div class="selected">
      some text
      <div class="selected"> this is the last div, but it can be anytime     changed and more childs of this element can be created</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="selected">
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
</div>
```